# Can't understand how to import AWS SDK on Kotlin Node JS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, kotlin, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to run a little example of an AWS Lambda written in Kotlin JavaScript, server side, which gets a parameter from the AWS SSM Parameter Store, and returns it through a REST call usig AWS API Gateway.

I came from Kotlin Java and mainly Java, so my main issue is: how do I import the `aws-sdk` dependency?

I've added it to my `package.json` and next I run `npm install`. 
I've tried importing it declaring something like this:

```
external fun require(module:String):dynamic
...
val aws = require("aws-sdk")
val ssm = aws.SSM()
...
```

But when I've "compiled" my project, the AWS SDK doesn't appear in the big index.js file generated from Kotlin.

Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `But when I've "compiled" my project, the AWS SDK doesn't appear in the big index.js file generated from Kotlin.` but does it work though?

Comment: It isn't supposed to appear there. `index.js` generated by the Kotlin compiler includes only the results of compiling your Kotlin code. If you want to package all of your dependencies in a single .js file, you need to use something like webpack.

Comment: @JonasW. no, it doesn't work. Since I don't really know if I'm importing it correctly.

Comment: @yole I'll take a look at webpack then, thank you.

Comment: "doesnt work" ... Debug?! Whats the error?

Comment: @JonasW. `Cannot find module 'aws-sdk'`. So probably I'm not packing the modules with my lambda.

Comment: @abierto no, you just havent installed it!!! `npm install aws-sdk`, them run again...